# PlayFramework 2.4 и SameSite

Tags: scala, playframework

JVM version:      OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_242 (25.242-b08) Private Build

Scala version:    2.11.6

Play version:     2.4.11

Akka version:     2.4.0

Akka remote:      127.0.0.1:2552

Akka leader:      127.0.0.1:2551

SBT version:      0.13.8

В данной версии Play нет поддержки(могу ошибаться), 
проект на данный момент нельзя иммигрировать, но какое то решение необходимо

Как добавить в play.api.mvc.Cookie дополнительный параметр SameSite, подскажите хотя бы как это захардкодить как временное решение